# retrieve value from item from object with a number as key name

Tags: php, object

I got this result:

```
Array 
(
  [author] =>  stdClass Object
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [name] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [$t] => Monica Orozco
                            )

                        [uri] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [$t] => http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/fyzB8GEofMof20wNuDxKIg
                            )

                        [yt$userId] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [$t] => fyzB8GEofMof20wNuDxKIg
                            )

                    )

            )
)
```

i've tried

`echo $result['author']->0->name->$t;`

`echo $result['author']->[0]->name->['$t'];`

but no go, maybe I should just throw it in a foreach? there must be a way i'm obviously missing :)

**--- edit**

Turns out you select a numbered key with quotes and curly brackets, who knew? :D
`echo $result['author']->{'0'}->name->{'$t'};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author is an array, but it's values are objects (ie author is an array which contains objects, not an object itself)

```
    echo $result['author'][0]->name->{'$t'};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $result['author'][0]->name->{'$t'};
```

Must be the code for it. It will be great if you watch this tutorial: [ARRAYS TUTORIAL](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=38)